# How to get Gmail (Google Mail) to automatically spellcheck emails being written?

Tags: gmail, text, spell-check

Gmail seems to, by default, turn off automatic spell-checking when one is composing an email.

Here is an animated GIF showing the issue in both the Firefox and Chrome web browsers:

[image: animation showing Google Mail not having automatic spell-checker enabled by default]

Is there a way to have spell-checking enabled by default?

Answer (score 1):

Chrome has a spellchecker built in: `chrome://settings/languages`, scroll down to advanced:
[image: Chrome spell check enabled]
"Check spelling" in GMail is a one off check.

Comment: Does it work for you in Gmail?  See the animated image in the question showing an example of it not working.

Comment: Yep, definitely works in the GMail compose window too.